# Is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<PizzaState>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I try to create pizzas$ that receive from store but have red sight on this .

`this.pizzas$`

I don't know why this happened but when i delete 
`: Observable<PizzaState>`
this this fix but i want to do with strongly type how can i fix it?

full code

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ProductesState } from '../shared/models/productesState.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PizzaState } from '../shared/models/pizzaState.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-read',
  templateUrl: './read.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./read.component.css']
})
export class ReadComponent implements OnInit {

  public pizzas$: Observable<PizzaState>;

  constructor(private store: Store<ProductesState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.store.select('pizzas').subscribe(store => {
      this.pizzas$ = store;
    });

  }

}
```

my reducer

```
import { PizzaState } from 'src/app/shared/models/pizzaState.model';
import * as fromPizzas from '../actions/pizzas.action'

export const initialState: PizzaState = {
    data: [],
    loaded: false,
    loading: false
}

export function reducer
    (state: PizzaState = initialState, action: fromPizzas.PizzasAction): PizzaState {

    switch (action.type) {

        case fromPizzas.LOAD_PIZZAS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        }

        case fromPizzas.LOAD_PIZZAS_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loaded: true,
                loading: false
            }
        }

        case fromPizzas.LOAD_PIZZAS_FAIL: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loaded: false,
                loading: false
            }
        }

        default: {
            return state;
        }

    }

}
```

and inside node module

```
    StoreModule.forRoot(
      { 'pizzas': reducers.pizzas }
    )
```

Thank for help :-)

Comment: You're are selecting store state (which is a plain object) and trying to assign it to a variable of type `Observable<PizzaState>;` which is not correct. Maybe you wanted to do only `pizzas$ = this.store.select('pizzas')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be subscribing if you want it to be an Observable, as the subscription will unwrap it from the Observable.  You have two options:

```
public pizzas$: PizzaState;
...
this.store.select('pizzas').subscribe(store => {
  this.pizzas$ = store;
});
```

or

```
public pizzas$: Observable<PizzaState>;
...
this.pizzas$ = this.store.select('pizzas');
```

Comment: What better approach? and The second approach don't work to me , give me an object "Store {_isScalar: false, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: ReducerManager, source: Store, operator: DistinctUntilChangedOperator}" and isn't  Observable<PizzaState>

Comment: Depends on how you're using it.  If you are trying to reference it in your template (.html file).  I would use the second approach and in the html you would reference it as pizzas$ | async.  If you want to reference it in your typescript I'd use the first approach which will unbox the observable so you are just dealing with a PizzaState object.  Keep in mind if using the first approach you need to worry about unsubscribing from the observable when your component is destroyed.

Comment: Generally speaking though the second approach is recommended if at all possible.  Even if you're using it in the typescript. It does require a certain amount of understanding about how Observables work though to deal with it properly.  I would need context about how you're trying to use it though to really offer advice.

Comment: so if second approach better i will prefer it , but this give me another object . when i print on reducer this return me the right object but inside component give me another , what can be the reason?

Comment: When you are using a selector it gives you an observable that will emit values whenever the value in the store changes.  It doesn't directly give you the value.  There are a number of approaches to get the value out of it (the simplest being option 1 above, again keeping in mind you need to unsubscribe).  Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do with that data I can't really tell you for sure how to use it.